# Show that a random variable $S\leadsto Geom(s)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables such that $X_n  \leadsto$ $\mathcal Geom(p)$ and $T\leadsto$ $\mathcal Geom(r)$  another random variable $(X_n \perp T$ for all $n)$. Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^TX_k$.

- Show that the charactrestic function of $T$ is given by $$\varphi_T(t)=\frac{re^{it}}{1-(1-r)e^{it}}$$
- Find the characteristic function of $S$.
- Deduce that $S\leadsto Geom(s)$ with $s$ to define.

---

- 

\begin{align*} \varphi_T(t)&=E(e^{itT}) \\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p(T=n)(e^{it})^n \\&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r(1-r)^{n-1}(e^{it})^n\\&=re^{it}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-r)^n(e^{it})^n\\&=\frac{re^{it}}{1-(1-r)e^{it}}\end{align*}

- $S$ is a sum of iid random variables so, \begin{align*} \varphi_S(t)&=E(e^{itS})\\&=\prod_{k=1}^T \varphi_{X_k}(t) \\&=\left( \frac{re^{it}}{1-(1-r)e^{it}} \right)^T\end{align*}
  I got stuck here ! So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two hints: First, the characteristic function of $X_k$ should involve $p$, not $r$.

Second, $S$ is a sum of a random number of $X$'s, so you cannot write
$$E(e^{itS})=\prod_{k=1}^T\phi_{X_k}(t),$$ which equates the non-random LHS to a RHS that still depends on the random variable $T$.

Instead, condition on the value of $T$:
$$E(e^{itS})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(T=n)E(e^{itS}\mid T=n)
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(T=n)E\left(e^{it(X_1+\cdots+X_n)}\right).$$ The final equality exploits the independence between $T$ and $(X_1,\ldots X_n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @grand_chat